# I need to search for relative positions of an item in a 2 dimensional range

Tags: google-sheets

So, I need to search a table for the column positions of a certain text (There are multiple of the same text in different rows), and return all their positions so i can calculate their avarage column position. This is on Google Sheets.

Comment: As ever, please share a link to your sheet or to a copy of your sheet, being sure to set the share permission for the link to "Anyone with the link can edit." I'm sure your post makes sense to you, but that is only because you already know what you mean, what your sheet and data look like, what your end goal is, etc. We "out here" do not. The only way to receive quality solutions is if we can also see and access what you are seeing and accessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pending more information about what the data looks like, you could try something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(average(flatten(if(A1:C4="x",column(A1:C4),))))
```

[image]

Actually you don't need the flatten to get the average:

```
=ArrayFormula(average(if(A1:C4="x",column(A1:C4),)))
```